# Actions-on-Google Custom Push Message explained

Tags: push-notification, actions-on-google

I am unable to pass additional information via custom push message.

I have push notifications sending to my device, a little icon shows up, when I click on it, my pipeline sees the request, however, the "argument" field is auto-populated with "boolValue" instead of a custom value field I am trying to set.

Below is the payload that I send to as a customPushMessage.

```
 {
     "customPushMessage": {
         "target": {
             "userId": "[User - Id - Omitted]",
             "intent": "TellJoke",
             "argument": {
                  "rawText": "Target Argument Raw Text",
                  "textValue": "Target Argument Text Value",
                  "name": "Target Argument Name"
              },
              "locale": "en-US"
          },
          "userNotification": {
              "title": "User Notification Title",
              "text": "User Notification Text"
           }
      }
}
```

I am expecting to be able to see within the request body the argument values.

Based on the documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/rest/Shared.Types/AppResponse#custompushmessage) I should be able to pass through an argument (or more since I am using v2).

Also, what purpose does the "userNotification::text" field serve, as it does not display in the notification, only the "title" and "intent description" do.

Answer (score 0):

So the argument values are posted on a "URL" element under "rawInputs"

```
 "rawInputs": 
 [
      {
        "inputType": "URL",
        "url": "[...]&param.Target Argument Name=Target+Argument+Raw+Text"
      }
 ]
```